# How to not send Notification if current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications, comments

If I make a comment on my own thing I shouldn't get a notification about it. How can we remove this "feature"?

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :create_notification
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :comment_likes   
  has_many :likers, through: :comment_likes, class_name: 'User', source: :liker
  belongs_to :habit
  belongs_to :stat
  belongs_to :valuation
  belongs_to :goal
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true
  default_scope { order('created_at') }

private

  def create_notification
    author = 
      if goal
        goal.user
      #elsif comment_like
      # comment_like.user
      elsif habit
       habit.user
      elsif stat
        stat.user
      elsif valuation
        valuation.user
      end
    notifications.create(
      comment:      self,
      likes:        likes,
      habit:        habit,
      stat:         stat,
      goal:         goal,
      valuation:    valuation,
      user:         author,      
      read:         false
    )
  end
end
```

Comments can be made on goals, valuations, stats, & habits.

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:destroy]

  def index
    @notifications = current_user.notifications
    @notifications.each do |notification|
      notification.update_attribute(:read, true) 
    end
  end


    def destroy
      @notification = Notification.find(params[:id])
      @notification.destroy
      redirect_to :back
    end

private

  def correct_user
    @notification = current_user.notifications.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Not authorized to edit this notification" if @notification.nil?
  end
end
```

**CommentsController**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_commentable, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @comments = @commentable.comments
  end

  def new
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.persisted?
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Comment was updated."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to @comment.commentable, notice: "Comment destroyed."
  end

  def like
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment_like = current_user.comment_likes.build(comment: @comment)
    if @comment_like.save
      @comment.increment!(:likes)
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Too many likes'
    end  
    redirect_to(:back)
  end

  private

  def set_commentable
    @commentable = find_commentable
  end

  def set_comment
    @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def correct_user
    @comment = current_user.comments.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Not authorized to edit this comment" if @comment.nil?
  end

  def find_commentable
    if params[:goal_id]
      Goal.find(params[:goal_id])
    elsif params[:habit_id]
      Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    elsif params[:valuation_id]
      Valuation.find(params[:valuation_id])
    elsif params[:stat_id]
      Stat.find(params[:stat_id])
    end
  end

  def comment_params
    params[:comment][:user_id] = current_user.id
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :commentable, :user_id, :like)
  end
end
```

Please let me know if you need further code or explanation. Live long & prosper :]

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you should not rely on callbacks. Especially if, like in this case, your callback must access data which is not available outside the context of the model.

The solution is simple. Rather than creating the comment calling ActiveRecord methods directly in your controller, define a custom method in the Comment itself.

```
class Comment
  # ...

  def self.create_comment(user, attributes)
    transaction do
        comment = new(attributes)
        if comment.save
            create_notification(user)
            # other after creation methods here
        end
        comment
    end
  end
end
```

Now the `create_notification` has access to the current user. Then, in your controller:

```
def create
  comment = Comment.create(current_user, params[:comments])
  if comment.persisted?
    # saved
  else
    # not saved
    # comment.errors
  end
end
```

There are several variations. You can also work always with an instance.

```
class Comment
  # ...

  def create_comment(user, attributes)
    transaction do
        comment.attributes = attributes
        if result = comment.save
            create_notification(user)
            # other after creation methods here
        end
        result
    end
  end
end

def create
  comment = Comment.new
  if comment.create_comment(current_user, params[:comments])
    # saved
  else
    # not saved
    # comment.errors
  end
end
```

Whatever is your implementation, the point is that callbacks should not be abused. In particular, they should be used to guarantee consistency within the same model, and you should not start introducing explicit dependencies between models or your code will quickly become slow and unmaintainable.

Comment: You are going to spend a lot more time on some hacky way to get it work in as a model callback...

Comment: Good answer, this is probably a candidate for a [service](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services) which seem to be all the rage in rails these days.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com It's not just about performance. You pretend to be able to access a controller environment information from the model, which is simply not possible (technically speaking you could still pass the data around using the current thread or a shared class variable, but you don't really want to do that). My proposal addresses this problem, and it doesn't really require that much effort.

Comment: Hi @SimoneCarletti. I'm back in action and I've been toying around with your code. What do you mean for me to put here `# other after creation methods here` can you just give me an example? And I added the comments controller code to the question because I'm having a hard time implementing what you put with what I had, which uses `@comment` and `@commentable`. Hopefully this doesn't come to you too late. Thanks for your help!